# Create horizontal list in notebook

Tags: notebooks

I want to create a multiple choice question paper and list the options horizontally. I am only looking at very simple document with horizontal list. What I want:

1. What is 1+1?

   a) 2 b) 4 c) 3 d) 7

Is there any correct way to do it with cells other than manually using spacebars?

Comment: Did you have a look at `Grid`, `Row` and such? Might come in handy...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To give you an idea how to go about that:

```
ans = {2, 4, 3, 7};

Row[Flatten[
  MapIndexed[{FromCharacterCode[#2[[1]] + 96] <> ") ", #1, 
     Spacer[20]} &, ans]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
Grid[{Flatten@
   MapIndexed[{FromCharacterCode[#2[[1]] + 96] <> ")", #1, 
      Spacer[10]} &, ans]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Row` and `Grid` behave differently regarding linewrapping, and `Grid` can of course be extended to 2D.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `TableForm`, e.g.

```
TableForm[{{"a)", 2, "b)", 4, "c)", 3, "d)", 7}},
 TableSpacing -> {1, 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A list of questions and answers:

```
questionsAndAnswers = StringJoin /@ {"question" ~~ #[[1]], "answer" ~~ #[[1]] ~~ #[[2]], "answer" ~~ #[[1]] ~~ #[[3]], "answer" ~~ #[[1]] ~~ #[[4]], 
 "answer" ~~ #[[1]] ~~ #[[5]]} & /@ (Join @@ # & /@ 
Thread[{List /@ ToString /@ Range[5], CharacterRange["a", "d"]}, List, 1])
(*{{"question1", "answer1a", "answer1b", "answer1c", "answer1d"},
  {"question2", "answer2a", "answer2b", "answer2c", "answer2d"},
  {"question3", "answer3a", "answer3b", "answer3c", "answer3d"},
  {"question4", "answer4a", "answer4b", "answer4c", "answer4d"},
  {"question5", "answer5a", "answer5b", "answer5c", "answer5d"}} *)
```

**Using `Grid`:**

```
Column[Grid[#, Spacings -> {2, Automatic}, Alignment -> Left] & /@ 
MapIndexed[{{First@#2 , #1[[1]]},
 {"", Row[{"a)", #1[[2]], "b)", #1[[3]], "c)", #1[[4]], "d)", #1[[5]]}, Spacer[5]]}} &, questionsAndAnswers]]
```

[image]

**Using `StringForm`:**

```
Column[StringForm["`1` \t`2` \n\t  `3`) `4`\t `5`) `6`\t `7`) `8`\t `9`) `10`", 
Sequence @@ (Riffle[#, CharacterRange["a", "d"], {3, -1, 2}])] & /@
MapIndexed[Join @@ {#2, #1} &, questionsAndAnswers]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You may try

```
Dynamic@x
Row[{"What is 1+1", Spacer[10], Control[{x, {2, 4, 7}}]}]
```